# 500 :: Error 500 in joomla login module

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

i'm getting     `500 :: Error 500`  in joomla login module.

When the password or username is typed wrongly(only in the server). This is the link of the live project http://bluepink.co.in/login  but error message is displayed in the localhost.

And Having problem with User mail activation link. Users are not activated when the activation link is clicked.

Using Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart.
I have enabled htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen due to the `temp directory` path or `log directory` invalid path.

check the path of those folders from your global configuration and make sure the path is correct and those folders have write permission too.

If this not solve your problem try to comment this line..
`$this->triggerEvent('onUserLoginFailure', array((array) $response));` on   `libraries/joomla/application/application.php`

Also about the activation link issue may get fixed with these.

Hope this will fix the issue.