# Unable to login in joomla site

Tags: joomla, authentication, joomla2.5

I am getting error code 500 when i try to login in my joomla site(not admin).Everything was working fine few days before but now i am unable to login the site.

[image: Error page which i get]

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514682/500-error-500-in-joomla-login-module/21544817#21544817

Comment: Actually the problem was that i have entered wrong username.

Comment: check the mentioned file path on config and make sure its proper. may be error log is the problem